# Counting and selecting data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

My data:

```
STAFF
(id, name,outlet)
=====================
(1, 'John','WA'),
(2, 'Mary', 'WA'),
(3, 'Wilson', 'PH'),
(4, 'James', 'NY'),

OUTLET    
(name, supervisorid)
============
('WA', 2),
('PH', 3),
('NY', 4),
```

I am looking for the following output

```
outlet,supervisorname,noofstaffinoutlet
WA,John,2
PH,Wilson,1
NY,James,1
```

I am able to count the no of staff using

```
  select s.outlet ,count(s.outlet) from STAFF s group by s.outlet;
```

How can I add in the supervisor name of the outlet as well?

I tried adding in `STAFF.id = OUTLET.superviorid` but if I do so my count becomes 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with `staff` twice.

```
SELECT o.name AS outlet, s1.name AS supervisorname, IFNULL(COUNT(s2.id), 0) AS nooffstaffinoutlet
FROM outlet AS o
JOIN staff AS s ON o.supervisorid = s.id
LEFT JOIN staff AS s2 on o.name = s2.outlet
```

Using `LEFT JOIN` and `IFNULL()` allows the query to show `0` for outlets with no staff.

Answer (score 1):

You could join outlet with staff twice - once to get the supervisor id and once in an aggregated query to get the number of employees:

```
SELECT o.name, s.name, c.cnt
FROM   outlet o
JOIN   staff s ON s.id = o.supervisorid
JOIN   (SELECT   outlet, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM     staff
        GROUP BY outlet) c ON c.outlet = o.name
```